# Sharepoint 2013 workflow: Set dynamic value in a listitem column

Tags: workflow, updatelistitems

I am using SharePoint 2013. I have created a workflow. This workflow is triggered on a contenttype on a list. I would like to update some listitem column. But I would like to set the value dynamic like "currentItem[ColumnA]" - 5. Is this possible?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "Do a Calculation" action and perform the calculation and output the value to a workflow variable.Use that variable to update the list item value.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the dynamic value into some variable and after that set the column value to that workflow variable.